# Webservices c# - mixing Post and Get

Tags: c#, web-services, post, get

is there a way to mix Post & Get Parameters in C# webservices?

I want to send some parameters in the URL and other in the body.

Comment: What web service? Web Api?

Comment: not webApi. WebService.asmx